# neo4j "try" to create relationship to node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How can I write the next cyhper query without error?

```
Match (n: {id :"someid"}),(x {id:"otherId"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[]->(t:Other)

merge x-[]->(t)`
```

The problem is that there is a cance that `t` will be null and ill get an error:
`Expected to find a node at t but found nothing Some(null)`

this is the complete query:

```
MATCH (traveler:${labels.N_TRAVELER} {id: {traveler}.id})
        OPTIONAL MATCH (traveler)-[r:${labels.R_TRAVELER_LATEST_EVENT}]->(prev:${labels.N_EVENT})
        OPTIONAL MATCH (interest:${labels.N_INTERESTS}) WHERE interest.id IN {interests}

        DELETE r
        MERGE (traveler)-[:${labels.R_TRAVELER_LATEST_EVENT}]->(trip:${labels.N_TRIP_EVENT})
        ON CREATE SET trip={trip}

        MERGE (traveler)-[:${labels.R_TRAVELER_WRITE_TRIP}]->(trip)
        MERGE (trip)-[:${labels.R_TRIP_INTEREST}]->(interest)

        WITH trip, collect(prev) as prevs
        UNWIND prevs as prev
        MERGE (trip)-[:${labels.R_EVENT_PREV_EVENT}]->(prev)
        WITH trip
        RETURN properties(trip) as trip`
```

all the `labels.` are just strings.. `{interests}` is an array of ids

Basically im tying to create a linked list of trips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution is to use only MATCH, which will then stop the query if there are no `t` nodes.

```
MATCH (n {id:"someid"}), (x {id:"otherId"})
MATCH (n)-->(t:Other)
MERGE (x)-[:RELATIONSHIP]->(t)
```

The second solution in case this query portion is part of a larger query and you need to do stuff afterwards is to collect the t, in the case of null the collection will be empty and thus you can iterate only if it contains elements :

```
MATCH (n {id:"someid"}), (x {id:"otherId"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-->(t:Other)
WITH n, x, collect(t) as ts
UNWIND ts as t
MERGE (x)-[:RELATIONSHIP]->(t)
WITH n, x
// continue query
```

Comment: the `UNWIND` part is exectly what i need and its working.. but there is no more elegant solution? like merge where t is not null or something like that?

Comment: Currently Cypher lacks a bit of conditionals, I'm sure it will come. I'm afraid I don't see something more elegant right now

Comment: Something is not right.. the Relationship is being created but after that im doing `with n return n` and it returns empty.. any ideas?

Comment: Can you paste the complete query you try now

Comment: is the linked list created ?

Comment: if you can try to return id(trip), properties(trip) , at least we can see the trip is  returned but it doesn't hold properties then

Comment: Yes. But the on the first time there us no return value and on the second time there is more then one line returned. And i expected every time to get one record

Comment: Even id(trip) doesn't return

Comment: mmh this is hard to say actually, so nothing returned at all ?

Comment: Not when trying to create the first node on the list.. (where prev is null)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the workaround I would use to handle the optional `MERGE`:

```
MATCH (n {id:"someid"}), (x {id:"otherId"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-->(t:Other)
FOREACH(y IN CASE WHEN t IS NULL THEN [] ELSE [1] END | MERGE (x)-[:RELATIONSHIP]->(t));
```

The `FOREACH` will only do the `MERGE` if `t` is not `NULL`.

Comment: thanks this is working but I as the same problem as before.. i cannon return `x` it always empty.. any ideas?

Comment: With neo4j 3.0, if create some minimal test data and end my query with `RETURN x`, I always get `x` returned. This is even if the `OPTIONAL MATCH` fails. What neo4j version are you using?

Comment: 3. Im runnibg the same query as in the question just with the foreach loop

Comment: My query is the same as the first query in your question, except for the `FOREACH` clause.